# War card game Crashes on start

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that plays the card game war(I haven't gotten to the war part yet). Right now I've made a Japplet class and a Deck Class and can figure out why my program isn't working. I don't have any red lines. Right now my Deck class creates the deck and I'm trying to create a string called "card" to bring over to WarUI class to see if it is working, but when I start the applet it crashes.

**Edit**: Now that that is working, some cards repeat before it hits 52 cards. How would I go about making it so cards don't repeat. I've been trying to search and it seems like array list would work but I don't understand how to use that properly

```
public class FullDeck {

    String card = "";
    public FullDeck()
    {
        int[]deck = new int[52];
        String [] suits = {"Heart" + "Diamond" + "Spade" + "Club"};
        String [] numbers = { "2" + "3" + "4" + "5" + "6" + "7" + "8" + "9" + "10" + "Jack" + "Queen" + "King" + "Ace" };

        for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)deck[i]=i;
            for(int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
            {
                int index = (int)(Math.random()*deck.length);
                int temp = deck[i];
                deck[i] = deck[index];
                deck[index]=temp;
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {
                String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
                String num = numbers[deck[i] % 13];
                card = "Card number " + deck[i] + ": " + num + " of " + suit;
            }
        }
    }
}

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WarUI extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

    FullDeck deck = new FullDeck();
    JTextArea displayLabel = new JTextArea("Enter a letter to guess the phrase."); //sets label to display message


     JTextField inputBox = new JTextField(40); //sets text field
     JButton runButton = new JButton("Run"); //button that starts program
     Container con = getContentPane(); //gets container

     public void init() {
         con.setLayout(new FlowLayout());//sets flowlayout
         con.add(new JLabel());      //jlabel container
         con.add(inputBox);  //input box container
         con.add(runButton);  //run button container
         con.add(displayLabel); //display label container

         runButton.addActionListener(this);//looks to see if run is clicked
         inputBox.addActionListener(this);//looks to see if input box is used
     }

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          displayLabel.setText("You Drew: " + deck.card); //displays hiddenPhrase
     }
}
```

Comment: Formatting your code would be a helpful start

Comment: `String [] suits = {"Heart" + "Diamond" + "Spade" + "Club"};` you initialise your arrays with only 1 string value. Use `,` instead of `+`.

Comment: A debugger tells you these kind of problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can check to see if all your information is doing okay, is to have it print to the console while your program is running. For example, before you have your card display, you can do:

```
System.out.println(//information that you want to check);
```

This is a very simple and especially very effective form of debugging so that you can figure out if your code is working or not

Another issue, which I see has been addressed before, is:

```
String [] suits = {"Heart" + "Diamond" + "Spade" + "Club"};
String [] numbers = { "2" + "3" + "4" + "5" + "6" + "7" + "8" + "9" + "10" + "Jack" + "Queen" + "King" + "Ace" };
```

These need to be `,` instead

```
String [] suits = {"Heart" , "Diamond" , "Spade" , "Club"};
String [] numbers = { "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" , "7" , "8" , "9" , "10" , "Jack", "Queen" , "King" , "Ace" };
```

Using `+` in a string fashion such as `"Heart" + "Diamond"` is what is known as concatenating, or joining the two strings together.

Hope it helps